# Is there a way to get the User Name of the Office account logged in to Microsoft Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access, office365, ms-office

I have seen other posts on getting the Windows account username, but I am looking to get the username from the associated microsoft office account logged in to ms Access.

We use Office 365 for our accounts and I want to be able to get the logged in users name using VBA in access if possible.

Comment: Review https://www.devhut.net/2020/10/07/vba-determine-microsoft-office-logged-in-user-account/

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45617924/office-365-username-to-vba-in-access-2016